# Checking If Key Exists in Complex Multidimensional Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I am storing users' locations and items assigned to them in different tables. Think it as there are items user is selling and the location of the item is assigned to the user.

I am using radius to retrieve users' locations. I can retrieve all items if I use 10km radius. However, I want to separate items to each km, such as:

```
- 1km
  - Guitar
  - Sofa
- 2km 
  - Citroen
  - Renault
  - Piano
```

The problem is that the query works like this so if I use '10km' as radius, it fetches everything from 0 to 10km:

```
let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 10)
```

So it logs like:

```
- 1km
  - Guitar
  - Sofa
- 2km 
  - Guitar
  - Sofa
  - Citroen
  - Renault
  - Piano
```

---

I thought one way could be using a for loop and storing it to a dictionary.

The approach I  tried:

```
var items = [Int: AnyObject]()

func retrieveItems() {

  let center = CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)

    for index in 1...25 {
        let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: Double(index))

       // after everything fetched

       self.items = [
           index : [itemId : value]
       ]

      // So, 'index' would be km 
      // 'itemId' is the id in db
      // 'value' would be 'key: value'

      // the database table looks like:
      //   - itemId:
      //      key:value
      //      key:value
    }
  }
```

Example dictionary tree:

```
 let dictionary = [
    1 : [
        "item1" : ["key": "value", "key": "value"],
        "item2" : ["key": "val", "key": "val"],
        ],
    2 : [
        "item3" : ["key": "val", "key": "val"],
        "item4" : ["key": "val", "key": "val"],
        "item5" : ["key": "val", "key": "val"],
    ]
]
```

As every time the index is increasing, it's fetching starting from 0km, so it's re-fetching already fetched stuff. But, using the dictionary, maybe I can make a check and if the 'itemId' is already in the dictionary, don't re-add it.

My question is, is there a way I can check if the 'itemId' is already added in the dictionary using above approach, so I don't add already added items? What is the way of achieving it in complex multidimensional dictionary like the one above?

---

Update: I tried something like this to check if the "itemId" exists

```
     if self.events.indexForKey(index) != nil {
         let radius = self.events[index]! as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
         print("km exists")
     } else {
         print("distance doesn't exist")
         self.items = [
             index : [itemId : value]
           ]            
     }
```

But it's always going inside `else` bit.

Comment: It's preferable you use a guard let statement in your last code example instead of a forced unwrapping and else clause for the successful code path. ;-)

Comment: @Randy Is that the trick? What is the way of overcome the whole problem?

Comment: @senty it would be helpful if you actually give us example contents of self.events, else it's difficult to tell why the updated answer is not working. How about you spin up a debugger and check the contents of self.events right before it evaluates the if clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to get duplicate events, you should just do a single query at 25 km, retrieve all keys, and then use client-side logic to filter those out into individual km groups. You can compute the distance between the returned keys coordinates and the center of your query [using some math](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/1d9061d0b1016035bcfcdc12f9a5ce3f9740cbfd/src/geoFire.js#L131-L141).

Comment: Your logic makes more sense than my latest approach (_using for loop 1...25 and retrieve 25 times store in array, also retrieve index-1 km, store array and get difference of two arrays_). But I couldn't figure out how to apply your client-side logic in Swift, and get data for each km. Can you please expand your answer on how to adapt this logic after retrieving data with a single query of 25km?